# Как я могу в GO полностью считать строку с пробелами?

Tags: golang

Как я могу это сделать? Пример, вводится строка

> cat dog kat kot jok

Как я могу полностью ее считать не зная изначально сколько в ней слов? fmt.scan() считает лишь одно слово

Comment: [Тут](https://golangdocs.com/golang-read-file-line-by-line)  есть примеры (найдено по запросу: `golang read line`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это делается с помощью пакета `bufio`:

```go
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    text, _ := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin).ReadString('\n')
}
```

Сначала мы создаём объект ридер (`bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)`) и передаём ему на вход стандартный ввод (`os.Stdin`)

И далее читаем оттуда всё до `\n`.